# Can't use Core Scaffold's 'hamburger' drawer toggle button when in cover mode

Tags: html, css, polymer, dart-polymer, core-elements

I've got a Polymer `<core-scaffold>` and I've put it in cover mode. Cover mode correctly moves the content of the main panel up onto the toolbar, but it disables the hamburger toggle button. No hover-border, no click event. Is this a bug? Is there another way to achieve the 'cover' effect?

Here's the code snippet of the scaffold and content -

```
    <core-scaffold responsiveWidth="1200px" mode="cover">
        <core-header-panel navigation flex mode="seamed">
            <core-toolbar horizontal layout end class="nav-toolbar">
                <core-item flex label="john.johnson@example.com"></core-item>
            </core-toolbar>
            <core-menu theme="core-light-theme" selected="0" selectedItem="{{item}}">
                <core-item label="Inbox"></core-item>
                <core-item label="Upcoming"></core-item>
                <core-item label="All Tasks"></core-item>
                <core-item label="Completed"></core-item>
            </core-menu>
        </core-header-panel>
        <div tool>{{item.label}}</div>
        <div fit horizontal center-justified layout class="card-container">
            <main-card flex></main-card>
        </div>
    </core-scaffold>
```

I've also got some margins on the top of my `card-container` class pushing it down so it lines up with the edge of the toolbar. Screenshot of what it looks like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pfh1.png).